# function needs to be improved, should return a _ and a number (however long)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've just been reviewing some functions on a project and found a problem.

I have the below in a function:

```
context = context.slice(-2);
```

This is supposed to get the the last bit of a string, for example 'something_2' the returned value should be '_2' but what if the function comes across 'something_230' currently the code above I assume will only return '30' and not '_230'.

```
var cleanItemId = function(context)
{
    context = context.slice(-2);
    return context;
}
```

I see this as a big problem, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem, I assume I need a reg expression, can someone point me in the correct direction?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume I need a reg expression, can someone point me in the correct direction?

A regular expression would work, but you don't necessarily *need* one. Approaches:

1. Use a regular expression.

   ```
   var m = context.match(/_(\d+)$/);
   if (m) {
       // Use `m[1]` to get the digits
   }
   ```

   That expression says: "A literal `_` followed by one or more digits followed by the end of the string, capturing the digits as a capture group."
2. Use `split('_')` and take the last element in the resulting array.

   ```
   var m = context.split('_');
   // Use `m[m.length - 1]` to get the digits
   ```
3. Use `lastIndexOf` to find the `_` and then grab the remainder of the string.

   ```
   var x = context.lastIndexOf('_');
   if (x !== -1) {
       // Use `context.substring(x + 1)` to get the digits
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this pretty much covers all reasonable solutions :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression (yet).

```
var str = "something_230";
var pos = str.lastIndexOf("_");
var out = str.substr(pos); // _230
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function seems to be useless :

```
context = context.replace(/^.*(_\d+)$/, '$1');
```

This one also works :

```
context = context.replace(/^.*(?=_\d+$)/, '');
```

If you want the first part :

```
context = context.replace(/_\d+$/, '');
```

Details here : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
context = context.split('_')[1];
```

This is if you're sure there is at last a `_` in the string. If you also need to parse the string as number:

```
var num = +context.split('_')[1];
```

Comment: What if the string is `"some_thing_230"`?

Comment: If there is the possibility of such case: `context.split('_').reverse()[0]`. I just reply based on the context given.